# Eclipse creating project index from command line

Tags: eclipse

How can I build C++ project index from command line by giving project name ?
I have searched in old question but didn't find any solution. 
In documentation also it is not given how to give project name to build index 
http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/guide/dom/index/prebuiltIndexes.html

Answer (score 0):

I successfully generated the pdom file, haven't verified if it's correct or not. Paste the command FYI.

```
$ECLIPSE_PATH -data $WS -arch x86 -nosplash -application org.eclipse.cdt.core.GeneratePDOM \
-target /tmp/test.pdom -source "$SRC_DIR" -id "" -include "$SRC_DIR" -vmargs -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
```